# How to show Spinner selected Item first in Android

Tags: android

In my application i have one spinner with data Cart,Trolley,Lorry,Truck etc..
in a button click i am saving spinner selected item and other items in the data base.
Now in another button click  i want to display all saved data,so in that i want to display previously saved spinner item first instead of default one.

How can i achieve this,please anyone suggest me

Ex:in spinner 1,2,3,4 displayed now if i select 3 and saved in data base now this time i want to show spinner data as 3,4,1,2.

Comment: Better to use an ArrayList and maintain the selected items and after items after that in the new ArrayList and all the items before the selected one, finally update the Adapter.

Comment: Guys, i got another problem from first time also i am getting spinner data from my database in that i have code likes vm00,vm01 etc. now how can i give position value as vm00,vm01 etc. instead of default arry index o,1,2 etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's much simple by getting index of spinner from DB and set the currently selected index on spinner item,for example if the spinner position stored in DB 
 then set it as 
       `spinner.setSelection(2);// Note : Position starts from 0,1,2,3 on array`

Comment: the above simple thing works for me thanks Senthil and thanks to all for your support

Answer (score 2):

You can change spinner content as below

```
String[] items = new String[] {"3","4", "1","2"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: how many times i can change spinner contents for example only i write 1,2,3,4 actually i have 15 array items if user selects any item i am saving it in the sqlite datbase if i give username and in another button click i need to show the saved value in the spinner

Comment: Here I have done static assignment on items array , you can do it programmatic.

Answer (score 2):

So I understand you correctly, you want to reorder the spinner items based on the user's previous selection? You just have to update the Adapter that you assigned to the spinner in that case.

I guess you wired up a simple ArrayAdapter in this case, so a basic solution would be to modify the order of the strings contained in that adapter, after selection.

Comment: Guys, i got another problem from first time also i am getting spinner data from my database in that i have code likes vm00,vm01 etc. now how can i give position value as vm00,vm01 etc. instead of default arry index o,1,2 etc..

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList listArray = new ArrayList();

    listArray.add("one");
    listArray.add("two");
    listArray.add("three");

      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listArray.toArray(strArray););
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
```

here took items as ArrayList and when user click on any item , break that arraylist in two part start to that point and  point to last. then take one temp arraylist and add second part then first part so  in that one .
and again call

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listArray.toArray(strArray););
            spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Guys, i got another problem from first time also i am getting spinner data from my database in that i have code likes vm00,vm01 etc. now how can i give position value as vm00,vm01 etc. instead of default arry index o,1,2 etc.